# Putty tunnel: Relay access denied

Tags: linux, putty, tunnel

I will try to connect I logged on locally (127.0.0.1) on Putty. Then I try to connect through the tunnel to the remote server.

I get a "Relay access denied" error. How can I solve it?

Comment: What service on the remote server are you trying to reach?  Relay access denied sounds like mail transport.  If you're trying to tunnel a particular service, usually you connect SSH to the remove server with a local port tunnel.

Comment: I wan't to reach a Mail Server Felix

Comment: Perhaps a question better asked on Server Fault?

Comment: It seems that I do not know how to configure the SSH tunnel

Comment: `Relay access denied` is an SMTP error message.  What command are you issuing that receives this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an SSH tunnel established:

In PuTTY, on the configuration screen go to Connection > SSH > Tunnels.  Set the source port to something like `2500`, which is actually `localhost:2500`.  Set Destination to `mailserver.example.com:25` (SMTP port) for whatever is the hostname of your mail server.

Connect over SSH, and you have now established a tunnel to port 25 on the destination host.

On your local machine, telnet to your local port, and you are now talking to port 25 on the remote machine.

```
telnet localhost 2500
```